# Converting GEE script to be used with rgee

Tags: javascript, r, google-earth-engine, rgee

I am attempting to run a script written for Google Earth Engine within Rstudio using the rgee package. I don't really know anything about Javascript and converting it to work within r has basically been a bash my head against a wall until something works experience.

Anyways in working through the below code I get to the indices/ft function section (4th code chunk) and receive the following message.

Error in .Call(_reticulate_py_str_impl, x) : reached elapsed time limit

I have used the setTimeLimit and setSessionTimeLimit functions with everything on inf (removed from the code examples below) but it did not seem to help and I receive the same message. I also used gc() to see if I could clear up some space but that had no effect. What can I do to make it stop freezing up at this point?

Also, I would appreciate any help in translating all of this script to work within Rstudio using the rgee package. So if you see anywhere else that I made an error that I am not catching or know how to approach the last bonus chunk at the end please let me know.

Here's the original script in case anyone wants to look
https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fmtd25%2FFire_severity%3AFire_atlas

```
library(rgee)

earthengine_python <- Sys.getenv("EARTHENGINE_PYTHON", unset = NA)
print(earthengine_python)
Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_PYTHON = earthengine_python)
ee_current_version <- system.file("python/ee_utils.py", package = "rgee")
ee_utils <- rgee:::ee_source_python(ee_current_version)
print(ee_utils$ee$'__version__')


library(dplyr)     
library(sf) 

library(googledrive)
library(googleCloudStorageR)
library(lwgeom)

library(reticulate)
library(jsonlite)
library(tidyverse)

# use for all other accounts
ee_Initialize()
```

Dataframe

```
df <- structure(list(FIRENAME = c("Ash", "Bitumul"), Year = c(1985L, 1985L), 
                     Fire_ID = c("1985-AZCNF-000071", "1985-AZASF-000148"), 
                     geometry = structure(list(structure(list(structure(c(-212345.986249991, -212789.545625001, -213239.380625002, -212691.334124997, -212345.986249991, 3816853.32925, 3816529.052375, 3816894.243125, 3817495.70187501, 3816853.32925), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), 
                                               structure(list(structure(c(-245447.64837499, -245857.643499993, -245697.833750002, -245154.533999994, -245447.64837499, 4037099.307625, 4037754.51575, 4038240.66825, 4037862.15787501, 4037099.307625), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))), 
                                          n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(input = "North_America_Lambert_Conformal_Conic", wkt = "PROJCRS[\"North_America_Lambert_Conformal_Conic\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"NAD83\",\n        DATUM[\"North American Datum 1983\",\n            ELLIPSOID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,\n                LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",6269]],\n        PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]]],\n    CONVERSION[\"unnamed\",\n        METHOD[\"Lambert Conic Conformal (2SP)\",\n            ID[\"EPSG\",9802]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of false origin\",0,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8821]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Longitude of false origin\",-108,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8822]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 1st standard parallel\",32,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8823]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Latitude of 2nd standard parallel\",36,\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8824]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Easting at false origin\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8826]],\n        PARAMETER[\"Northing at false origin\",0,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1],\n            ID[\"EPSG\",8827]]],\n    CS[Cartesian,2],\n        AXIS[\"(E)\",east,\n            ORDER[1],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9001]]],\n        AXIS[\"(N)\",north,\n            ORDER[2],\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1,\n                ID[\"EPSG\",9001]]]]"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -245857.643499993, ymin = 3816529.052375, xmax = -212345.986249991, ymax = 4038240.66825), class = "bbox"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(FIRENAME = NA_integer_, Year = NA_integer_, Fire_ID = NA_integer_), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity")))
```

Inputs and setup

```
## Script to develop and export spectral index metrics (see list below) for fires in North America. 
##    Script by Morgan Voss and Than Robinson - University of Montana
##    with revisions by Lisa Holsinger - U.S. Forest Service Rocky Mountain Research Station
##    and Ellen Whitman - Canadian Forest Service, Northern Forestry Centre
##    Oct 2019
##    For updates or questions on this code, please contact:  
##        Ellen Whitman, ellen.whitman@canada.ca
##        Lisa Holsinger, lisa.holsinger@usda.gov
##        Sean Parks, sean.parks@usda.gov



## This script backfills 'No Data' areas, which occur due to clouds, cloud-shadows, snow with imagery from
##    up to five years prior to fire for 'pre' fire imagery, and up to two years after fire for 'post' fire
##    imagery.  Note, data are mosaiced such that if 'clear' imagery exists for one year prior and one year after fire,
##    only that imagery is used, and additional imagery is used to fill 'no data' areas, in a successive manner.

##--------------------       INPUTS       ------------------------------##
## import shapefile with fire polygons as a feature collection - these must have the following attributes:
##    Fire_ID, Year

fires <-  ee$FeatureCollection(sf_as_ee(df)); ##Add your google earth engine account name between the two slashes. 
##Upload and name appropriately your 'Fires' shapefile as an asset in your directory  


## specify fire severity metrics to create
bandList <-  ('rdnbr_w_offset'); 

## Enter beginning and end days for imagery season as julian dates, adapt for your local fire season
startday <-  91;
endday   <-  273;

##  visualize fire perimeters
Map$centerObject(fires);
Map$addLayer(fires);

##--------------------    END OF INPUTS   ----------------------------##


##--------------------     PROCESSING     ----------------------------##
##-------- Initialize variables for fire perimeters  -----------------##
## create list with fire IDs  
fireID    <- ee$List(fires$aggregate_array('Fire_ID'))$getInfo();
fireName    <- ee$List(fires$aggregate_array('FIRENAME'))$getInfo(); 

nFires <- length(fireID);
nNames <- length(fireName);

##------------------- Image Processing for Fires Begins Here -------------##
## Landsat 5, 7, and 8 TOA Reflectance Tier 1 collections
##     Only include SLC On Landat 7
ls8SR <- ee$ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
ls7SR <- ee$ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR')
ls5SR <- ee$ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
ls4SR <- ee$ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT04/C01/T1_SR')

##///////////////////////////////
## FUNCTIONS TO CREATE NBR
##///////////////////////////////


## Returns vegetation indices for LS8
ls8_Indices <- function(lsImage){
  nbr <- lsImage$normalizedDifference(c("B5", "B7"))$toFloat()
  qa <- lsImage$select("pixel_qa")
  nbr$addBands(qa)
  lsImage$select(list(0,1), list("nbr", "pixel_qa"))$
    copyProperties(lsImage, list('system:time_start'))
}

## Returns vegetation indices for LS4, LS5 and LS7
ls4_7_Indices <- function(lsImage){
  nbr <- lsImage$normalizedDifference(c("B4", "B7"))$toFloat()
  qa <- lsImage$select("pixel_qa")
  nbr$addBands(qa)
  lsImage$select(list(0,1), list("nbr", 'pixel_qa'))$
    copyProperties(lsImage, list('system:time_start'))
}

## Mask Landsat surface reflectance images
## Creates a mask for clear pixels 
lsCfmask <- function(lsImg){
  quality <-lsImg$select('pixel_qa')
  clear <- quality$bitwiseAnd(8)$eq(0)$ ## cloud shadow
    And(quality$bitwiseAnd(32)$eq(0))$ ## cloud
    And(quality$bitwiseAnd(4)$eq(0))$ ## water
    And(quality$bitwiseAnd(16)$eq(0)) ## snow
  lsImg$updateMask(clear)$
    select(0)$                                  
    copyProperties(lsImg, list('system:time_start'))
}

## Map functions across Landsat Collections

ls8 <- ls8SR$map(ls8_Indices)$map(lsCfmask)
ls7 <- ls7SR$map(ls4_7_Indices)$map(lsCfmask)
ls5 <- ls5SR$map(ls4_7_Indices)$map(lsCfmask)
ls4 <- ls4SR$map(ls4_7_Indices)$map(lsCfmask)

## Merge Landsat Collections
lsCol <- ee$ImageCollection(ls8$merge(ls7)$merge(ls5)$merge(ls4)
```

Now here is the part I have problems with. When debugging line by line I get the
"Error in .Call(_reticulate_py_str_impl, x) : reached elapsed time limit"
message once I get to burnIndices3 and after each subsequent bunindices 4 - 8.

```
## ------------------ Create and Export Fire Severity Imagery for each fire -----------------##
indices <- ee$ImageCollection(fires$map(function(ft){
  ## use 'Fire_ID' as unique identifier
  fName    <-  ft$get("Fire_ID")
  
  ## select fire
  fire <-  ft
  fireBounds <-  ft$geometry()$bounds()
  
  ## create pre- and post-fire imagery
  fireYear <-  ee$Date$parse('YYYY', fire$get('Year'))
  
  ## Pre-Imagery
  preFireYear <-  fireYear$advance(-1, 'year')
  preFireIndices <-  lsCol$filterBounds(fireBounds)$
    filterDate(preFireYear, fireYear)$
    filter(ee$Filter$dayOfYear(startday, endday))$
    mean()$
    rename('preNBR')
  
  ## if any pixels within fire have no data due to clouds, go back two years (and up to five) to fill in no data areas
  ## two years back
  preFireYear2    <-  fireYear$advance(-2, 'year')
  preFireIndices2 <-  lsCol$filterBounds(fireBounds)$
    filterDate(preFireYear2, fireYear)$
    filter(ee$Filter$dayOfYear(startday, endday))$
    mean()$
    rename('preNBR')
  pre_check <-  preFireIndices$clip(fire)
  pre_filled <- pre_check$unmask(preFireIndices2)
  
  ## three years back
  preFireYear3    <-  fireYear$advance(-3, 'year')
  preFireIndices3 <-  lsCol$filterBounds(fireBounds)$
    filterDate(preFireYear3, fireYear)$
    filter(ee$Filter$dayOfYear(startday, endday))$
    mean()$
    rename('preNBR')
  pre_filled2<- pre_filled$unmask(preFireIndices3)
  
  ## four years back
  preFireYear4 <-  fireYear$advance(-4, 'year')
  preFireIndices4 <-  lsCol$filterBounds(fireBounds)$
    filterDate(preFireYear4, fireYear)$
    filter(ee$Filter$dayOfYear(startday, endday))$
    mean()$
    rename('preNBR')
  pre_filled3 <- pre_filled2$unmask(preFireIndices4)
  
  ## five years back
  preFireYear5 <-  fireYear$advance(-5, 'year')
  preFireIndices5 <-  lsCol$filterBounds(fireBounds)$
    filterDate(preFireYear5, fireYear)$
    filter(ee$Filter$dayOfYear(startday, endday))$
    mean()$
    rename('preNBR')
  pre_filled4 <- pre_filled3$unmask(preFireIndices5) 
  
  ## Post-Imagery
  postFireYear <-  fireYear$advance(1, 'year')
  postFireIndices <-  lsCol$filterBounds(fireBounds)$
    filterDate(postFireYear, fireYear$advance(2, 'year'))$
    filter(ee$Filter$dayOfYear(startday, endday))$
    mean()$
    rename('postNBR')
  
  ## if any pixels within fire have only one 'scene' or less, add additional year for imagery window
  postFireIndices2 <-  lsCol$filterBounds(fireBounds)$
    filterDate(postFireYear, fireYear$advance(3, 'year'))$
    filter(ee$Filter$dayOfYear(startday, endday))$
    mean()$
    rename('postNBR')
  post_check <-  postFireIndices$clip(fire)
  post_filled <-  post_check$unmask(postFireIndices2)
  fireIndices <-  pre_filled4$addBands(post_filled)
  
  ## create fire severity indices    
  ## calculate dNBR 
  
  burnIndices <-  fireIndices$expression(
    "(b('preNBR') - b('postNBR')) * 1000")$
    rename('dnbr')$toFloat()$addBands(fireIndices)
  
  ## calculate dNBR with Offset developed from 180-m ring outside the fire perimeter
  ring   <-  fire$buffer(180)$difference(fire)
  burnIndices2 <-  ee$Image$constant(ee$Number(burnIndices$select('dnbr')$reduceRegion(
    reducer = ee$Reducer$mean(),
    geometry = ring$geometry(),
    scale = 30,
    maxPixels = 1e9
  )$get('dnbr')))$rename('offset')$toFloat()$addBands(burnIndices) 

  burnIndices3 <-  burnIndices2$expression(
    "b('dnbr') - b('offset')")$
    rename('dnbr_w_offset')$toFloat()$addBands(burnIndices2)

  ## calculate RBR
  
  burnIndices4 <-  burnIndices3$expression(
    "b('dnbr') / (b('preNBR') + 1.001)")$
    rename('rbr')$toFloat()$addBands(burnIndices3)

  ## calculate RBR with offset  
  burnIndices5 <-  burnIndices4$expression(
    "b('dnbr_w_offset') / (b('preNBR') + 1.001)")$
    rename('rbr_w_offset')$toFloat()$addBands(burnIndices4)

  ## calculate RdNBR
  burnIndices6 <-  burnIndices5$expression(
    "(b('preNBR') < 0.001) ? 0.001 + 
      : b('preNBR')")$
    sqrt()$rename('preNBR2')$toFloat()$addBands(burnIndices5)
  
  burnIndices7 <-  burnIndices6$expression(
    "(b('dnbr') / sqrt(b('preNBR2')))")$
    rename('rdnbr')$toFloat()$addBands(burnIndices6)
  
  ## calculate RdNBR with offset
  burnIndices8 <-  burnIndices7$expression(
    "b('dnbr_w_offset') / sqrt(b('preNBR2'))")$
    rename('rdnbr_w_offset')$toFloat()$addBands(burnIndices7)
  
  burnIndices8 <-  burnIndices8$select(bandList)
  burnIndices8$set({
    ft$get('Fire_ID')
    ft$get('FIRENAME')
    ft$get('Year')}
  ) 

}))
```

Bonus chunk of code I haven't gotten to yet.

```
## ## Export fire indices for each fire  
nBands <-  bandList$length;

for (j = 0; j < nFires; j++){
  id   <- fireID[j];
  Name <-  id;
  fireExport <-  ee$Image(indices.filterMetadata('fireID', 'equals', id).first());
  fireBounds <-  ee$Feature(fires.filterMetadata('Fire_ID', 'equals', id).first()).geometry().bounds();
  firesname <-  fireName[j];
  Nameoffire <-  firesname;
  fireExport <-  ee$Image(indices.filterMetadata('fireName', 'equals', firesname).first());
  fireBounds <-  ee$Feature(fires.filterMetadata('FIRENAME', 'equals', firesname).first()).geometry().bounds();

  
  
  
  for (i == 0; i < nBands; i++) {
    bandExport <-  bandList[i];  
    exportImg <-  fireExport.select(bandExport);
    Export.image.toDrive({
      image: exportImg,
      ##description: Name + '_' + bandExport,
      ##fileNamePrefix: Name + '_' + bandExport,
      description: Name + '_' + Nameoffire + '_'  + bandExport,
      fileNamePrefix: Name + '_' + Nameoffire + '_' + bandExport,
      maxPixels: 1e13,
      scale: 30,
      crs: "EPSG:4326",
      folder: 'fires',      
      region: fireBounds
    })
  }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of problems here

1. Convert ee.Number objects to ee.String before parsing a date.

```r
## create pre- and post-fire imagery
fireYear <-  ee$Date$parse('YYYY', ee$Number$format(fire$get('Year')))
```

2. Delete plus operator in RdNBR.

```r
  ## calculate RdNBR
  burnIndices6 <-  burnIndices5$expression(
    "(b('preNBR') < 0.001) ? 0.001: b('preNBR')")$
    # if("b('preNBR') < 0.001"){
    # "b('preNBR') + 0.001"
    # } else {
    #   "b('preNBR')"})$
    sqrt()$rename('preNBR2')$toFloat()$addBands(burnIndices5)
```

3. Change `{}` to List:

```r
burnIndices8$set(
  list(
    Fire_ID=ft$get('Fire_ID'),
    FIRENAME=ft$get('FIRENAME'),
    Year=ft$get('Year')
  )
)
```

To avoid problems like **reached elapsed time limit** I highly recommend taking a look at https://r-earthengine.github.io/intro_03/ Section 18. See a reproducible example here: https://gist.github.com/csaybar/4f79c1dd63ea243d0d086a4bbd3829f3

Comment: Thanks a bunch I made your suggested changes. In your reproducible example lines 90-91 was there a reason  `nbr$addBands(qa)` was left out? Also, between lines 234 and 237 the burnindices6 was missing. Originally the equation for burnindices6 looked like ```"(b('preNBR') < 0.001) ? 0.001" +  ": b('preNBR')")``` which I found later was an If Else statement. What you saw in my example was just how I had tried to make it work but obviously didn't.

Comment: Sorry there was no reason, I just forget to copy it!

Comment: Okay, just checking. I'm looking over section 18 in your best practices paper now and trying to figure out how I can implement it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I'm going to leave this as unanswered for right now but hopefully I'll get the export suggestion working over the next day or so.

Comment: I added 
```assetid7 <- paste0(ee_get_assethome(), '/burnIndices7')
task7 <- ee_image_to_asset(burnIndices7, assetId = assetid7)
exportedStack7 <- ee$Image("users/mtd25/burnIndices7")```
between each occurrence of burnindices with updated numbers for task, assetid, and exported stack to match each burn indices number. Seems to work and "indices" shows up in the global environment now. Of course I am not completely sure that it is creating the desired output yet until I figure out theses for loops. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ csaybar In trying to further debug the indices imagecollection I tried using an example you have at r-spatial.github.io/rgee/reference/… to export it locally. I came up with the following error Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :    EEException: Image.load: Image asset 'users/mtd25/burnIndices7' not found. which would seem to me that there may be a problem with burnIndices6 not importing correctly to #7.

Comment: Hi @MikeD if you have another problem with you script, now related to exporting data from GEE using R. Please open another question adding a short and reproducible example.  Thanks!